# Using execlp to paste together contents of many files

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to use execlp and forked proceses to paste together groups of files. I have come up with something like this:

```
  for(int i=0; i<pair_counter; i++){
       int out_f = open(C[i],O_WRONLY);

       pid_t child = fork();
         if(child==0){
           char buffer[1000];
           dup2(out_f,1);
           close(out_f);
             sprintf(buffer, ".tmp/part%d*", i);
         execlp("paste",buffer,NULL);

         }
    }
```

and it produces errors like:

> .tmp/part0*: -: Input/Output error

while standard version using system() works properly:

```
for(int i=0; i<pair_counter; i++){
            char *buffer = calloc(1000, sizeof(char));
            sprintf(buffer, "paste .tmp/part%d* > %s", i, c_filenames[i]);
            system(buffer);
        }
```

I am preety new to c and Lnux so would be really gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paste command expects file names, not patterns, as its arguments. When you type something like "paste part1*" at a shell prompt, the shell expands the pattern "part1*" into a set of file names (eg. part11 part1.a part1-and-more), and invokes paste with all of those names.  There has been a lot written about unix shell concepts and syntax, so you should be able to find some easily.

If you change your program to:

```
 sprintf(buffer, "paste .tmp/part%d*", i);
 execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", buffer, NULL);
```

It should work.  I didn't exactly try it, but you didn't exactly post a complete problem, so...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char buffer[1000];
    sprintf(buffer, "paste *.c");
    return execlp("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", buffer, 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

This is a complete version, the kind you can make with only a moment of *what*?

Comment: I haven't posted the whole code as it is quite long, but everything has worked up until the point of changing call to system for execlp. I have tried your suggestion, but it changed the error to
`Can't open paste .tmp/part1* `
and so on

Comment: Not quite. It would need to be `execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", buffer, NULL);` But better might be `execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", buffer, NULL);` (no need to search path) Or `execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", buffer, NULL);` (search for shell in path).